# Faced TypeError: expect(...).toBeString is not a function when testing React app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I was testing React app and faced this error: `TypeError: expect(...).toBeString is not a function`. The code I am using is :

```
import React from "react";

import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import Footer from "../Footer/Footer";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<About />", () => {
  it("Check the type of value", () => {
    const props = {
      copyright: "Copyright 2019"
    };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Footer {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.prop("copyright")).toBeString();
  });
});
```

Comment: That's not listed [in the docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect), what made you think it *would* exist? Also that test seems pretty pointless, all you're checking is that the renderer and JSX works.

Comment: probably you was confused with [`jest-extended`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) package that provides `toBeString` among other custom matchers

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I found it here. https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-test-react-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-p

Comment: @skyboyer, hi what can I use instead of toBeString?

Comment: You can either use that package, or look at how they implemented it and recreate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using jest. So, `toBeString` is not a matcher in jest.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Comment: sorry Johnny but I got this error, Expected value to be of type string:
      "type of string"
    Received:
      "undefined"

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html